# Use One Content type's field as a reference in another content type's view?

Tags: views, entities, nodes

I have following requirements :

Add and List of Book
Add and List of Quiz related to book.

I have created content type for Book with field name : book_id,book_name,price etc..,here book_id will be unique in every time.

Also created content type for quiz with field name : quiz_name,my_book_id etc..

Now in view of quiz i have to show field quiz_name with book_name. How can it will be possible to map this field?

I refered too much like entity reference, node reference module etc but didnt get any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solutions is

**1.** In your Quiz content type remove book_id field , add another field with (each name you want here I named it my_book_id ) select type `node reference`  for it.

then in views, create a views of content type quiz, create a relation on my_book_id then you can add book title .

**2.** Another way is using php views field 
create a views with content type quiz, select quiz desire field, then add my_book_id field ,exlude it from dispaly then create php field , in value use something like this

```
<? 
 $node=node_load($data->mybookid); // this is not precise way, you should put nid in node_load(nid);
 print $node->title;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks 4 help. I added node reference type for my_book_id so its give me option like autosuggest, checkbox etc. I wants when quiz insert only user add my_book_id not added/choose book_title. so we have to try any another approach to find out solution?

Comment: @Chirag what is my_book_id ? node id of book contents?

Comment: @Chirag do you have custom module in your project?

Comment: my_book_id is field of quiz content type. and in view i want to get book name which book_id is same as my_book_id. I didnt use any custom module in my project.

Comment: In shot in core PHP we are using query like this : "select a.quiz_name,b.book_name from quiz as a,book as b where a.my_book_id=b.book_id" but in drupal view how can I fetch this?

Comment: @Chirag ok. one quick solution is  use text field in quiz (book_id) you should enter valid nid of book content type,then in views create quiz content views, add book_id field in list of views field, exclude it from display, then use php field , then use `node_load` to load book then print title.